# Why doesn't NSSet have a writeToFile method?

Tags: cocoa, foundation, nsset

I know that I can store NSSet's in an NSArray, but why isn't a dedicated writeToFile method provided? It must be a very common use case.

I just want to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `writeToFile` method of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` writes the contents as property list.

The reason `NSSet` lacks the method is that `NSSet` is not property list compliant.

But since `NSSet` can be initialized with an array and has an `allObjects` property to get an array the loss is not that bad.

Comment: Have you not just refined the question to being "Why is `NSSet` not property list compliant?"